# Listings: Format part of a string differently (markup language inside a string)

Tags: listings, strings

I made a new language definition for a .NET template engine where part of the strings in the C# code are markup.

Example:

```
string templateString = @"{% for name in names %} 
Hallo {{ name }} 
{% endfor %}";
```

Everything between {% and %} and {{ and }} is part of the template engine and should be formatted different from the string.

My language definition looks like this:

```
 \lstdefinelanguage{dotliquid}[Sharp]{C}
 {morecomment=[s][\color{liquidgreen}]{\{\%}{\%\}},
 morecomment=[s][\color{liquidgreen}]{\{\{}{\}\}}
 }
```

When I have normal C# code with template code inside (not inside a string) it works fine, but in the example above the complete string is formatted one way.

Is there any way to achieve this? I experimented with moredelim and deletestring but didn't manage to get the wanted result.

Comment: Hi. Were you already able to solve this problem? Perhaps this does not have an answer until now because it is difficult to set up this problem without enough background. Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for solvers to play with.